# How can I add an attribute to java annotation to all methods at once

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

I am currently working on a Java project (Eclipse IDE) and I have a custom annotation @CustomAnnotation. It already has several attributes.
Now I added a new attribute as part of project-improvement and I need to add this new attribute to my methods (and similarly to Classes). Is there an easier way other than manually adding that attribute to all my java methods? May be via Eclipse?

As an Example:

```
<code>
// My current ClassAnnotation
public @interface CustomAnnotation{
  boolean enableTest;
}

// My current MethodAnnotation
public @interface MethodAnnotation{
  boolean enableTest;
}

//My current class and method
@ClassAnnotation(enableTest = fasle)
Classs MyClass {
  @MethodAnotation(enableTest = false)
  public void myMethod() {}
}

//My NEW ClassAnnotation
public @interface CustomAnnotation{
  boolean enableTest;
  String[] testNames;
}

// My NEW MethodAnnotation
public @interface MethodAnnotation{
  boolean enableTest;
  String[] testNames;
}

// My NEW Class and Method looks like
@ClassAnnotation(enableTest = fasle,
                 testNames = { test1, test2})
Classs MyClass {
  @MethodAnnotation(enableTest = fasle,
                 testNames = { test1, test2})
  public void myMethod() {}
}
</code>
```

I tried to search for a clue across internet and stackoverflow but with no luck.
I could use some help from this community.

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be good enough if the attribute had a default value?

Comment: @immibis This option may not be the apt in my case because I need to mention this new attribute,value on method. Please see my reply to Axel's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to use "grep and replace" approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either of these:

1. Use a default value for the attribute (I'd re3commend this in your case).
2. Search and replace using regular expressions. Something like search for "^(@MethodAnnotation([^)])*)" / replace with "$1, myNewAttribute=123)" should work.

Comment: Option 1 may not be the apt in my case because I need to mention this new attribute,value on method. your Option 2 looks promising but, I am still trying to find a way if Eclipse can do this for me.

Comment: I am going to use second approach. Thanks.